# Using SymmetricEncryption with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, openssl

I am using [SymmetricEncryption](http://reidmorrison.github.io/symmetric-encryption/index.html) with rails 4 to encrypt certain attributes of my model. It worked well in development environment but does not work in production.
I get the error 
OpenSSL::Cipher bad decrypt 
when dercypting a value in the database.
The different thing is that in production, I have a unicorn server running 8 slaves. I want to understand how OpenSSL Cipher works. I found out that the one gets he error when they used different key and iv. But I have only one set for the same.
What other situations can cause such error?